# Running IDLE (python GUI)

Tags: python-2.7

When I load IDLE(python GUI), it shows an error message as follows

```
IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a subprocess or personal firewall is blocking the connection.
```

I have windows defender which I disabled, but still the error is as it is.
What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Delete Python. Reboot computer. After right click to setup and click **Run As Adminstrator**.